# How to transform color image to grayscale in java

Tags: java, grayscale

How can I transform color image to grayscale using java code?

A sample grayscale image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplest way is to draw to GRAY buffered image

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);  
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();  
g.drawImage(colorImage, 0, 0, null);  
g.dispose();
```

See more ways [here](http://www.codebeach.com/2008/03/convert-color-image-to-gray-scale-image.html)